# Library to overlay text on top of data URI images

Tags: library, javascript, image-processing, png

In HTML, I can use a data URI to display image to avoid requiring an HTTP request to fetch image resources. This can be useful for displaying icons.

For example:

```
<img width="128" height="128" title="" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
```

Will display:

[image: smiley icon]

What I'd like to do is dynamically overlay some text on top of this. For example:

[image: smiley icon with hello caption over it]

Is there a javascript library that will allow me to do this? Ideally, it will allow me to modify .pngs.

Comment: Interesting question. Should the change happen on the client side, after page load, or on the server side (with node.js, probably?) or somewhere in between?

Comment: @Marcel - Clientside.

Comment: Ok, how about like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708945/how-to-position-text-over-an-image-in-css It would require a slight change in how the page is built, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with some simple javascript that adds text after each image. I have created a jsFiddle for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/suterma/7npbxxkg/5/

However, positioning of the text is a bit difficult, and, the image is not physically altered. So, when a user right-clicks to download/view the image, the text is gone.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an HTML/Div based solution. The data URI I'm using is actually passed into a JS library I'm using to be drawn on an HTML canvas, so I need to modify the URI itself.